# How do I set a fixed name for apps on an Ubuntu lxde taskbar?

Tags: lxde

I have multiple Chrome and Firefox browsers running on Ubuntu LXDE, and I would like to assign a specific name to each browser so that when I glance at them on the taskbar, I can immediately identify which browser I am maximizing. The reason behind this is that I have around 20 browsers running, each serving a unique purpose for my projects. Currently, I find myself spending a few extra seconds trying to remember the exact location of a particular browser on the taskbar.

Ubuntu 20.04, LXDE 10

Comment: You haven't provided release details; so please provide. LXDE is no longer maintained by Ubuntu *flavors* thus is from upstream Debian on *supported* releases of Ubuntu (LXDE being *deprecated* along with its GTK2 libraries/toolkit & replaced by LXQt)

Comment: Are you sure you are using LXDE? Ubuntu 20.04 is supposed to use LXQt instead

Comment: Yes, i have installed it manually because i was used to it since ubuntu 18.